# Apply different loss function to part of tensor in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a custom loss function where it will apply different function to different part of tensor based on `groundtruth`.

Say for example the `groundtruth` is:

```
[0 1 1 0]
```

I want to apply `log(n)` to index 1, 2 (which is those whose value is 1 in the ground truth) of the output tensor, and apply `log(n-1)` to the rest.

How will I be able to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two masks.

- The first one masks out zeros, so you can apply it to your first loss function in which you only apply `log(n)` to those values of 1's.
- The second mask masks out ones, so you can apply it to your second loss function in which you apply `log(n-1)` to those values of 0's.

Something like:

```
input = tf.constant([0, 1, 1, 0], tf.float32)
mask1 = tf.cast(tf.equal(input, 1.0), tf.float32)
loss1 = tf.log(input) * mask1

mask2 = tf.cast(tf.equal(input, 0.0), tf.float32)
loss2 = tf.log(input - 1) * mask2

overall_loss = tf.add(loss1, loss2)
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

@greeness answer can be further simplified by directly using the input for masking without converting to bool and back to float:

```
ground_truth = tf.constant([0, 1, 1, 0], tf.float32)
your_tensor = tf.constant([1, 0, 1, 0], tf.float32)

loss = tf.log(ground_truth * your_tensor + (1 - ground_truth ) * (your_tensor - 1))
# loss = tf.log([0, 0, 1, -1])
```